# Select an item closest to bottom 25%

Tags: oracle, math

I have a query that selects a car closest to the average price of all cars:

```
 select  *
    from 
      (
        select USER.CAR.*, abs(CAR_PRICE - ( (select avg(CAR_PRICE) from USER.CAR ) ) ) as PriceDif
        from USER.CAR
        order by PriceDif
      ) 
    where rownum = 1
```

How can I change this to select the car closest to the most expensive of the bottom 25%? 
I changed it to:

```
select  *
    from 
      (
        select USER.CAR.*, abs(CAR_PRICE - ( (select avg(CAR_PRICE)*.75 from USER.CAR ) ) ) as PriceDif
        from USER.CAR
        order by PriceDif
      ) 
    where rownum = 1
```

And I got a result close to what I had anticipated, but is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That computation is incorrect. Rather, what you need is the `ntile()` function.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions101.htm

You are looking for the 25% which means you are looking for quartiles (n = 4). In the query below I show how to use this function to find the exact price you are looking for, and at the same time demonstrate that your computation gives a very different answer.

```
with
     p ( price ) as (
       select  200 from dual union all
       select  230 from dual union all
       select  400 from dual union all
       select  320 from dual union all
       select  540 from dual union all
       select  290 from dual union all
       select  340 from dual union all
       select  490 from dual union all
       select  380 from dual union all
       select  310 from dual union all
       select 4000 from dual union all
       select  350 from dual
     )
--  end of made-up test data; query begins below this line
select round(avg(price)*0.75, 2) as adjusted_avg_price,
       max(case when quartile = 1 then price end) as first_quartile_price
from   ( select price, ntile(4) over (order by price) as quartile
         from   p
       )
;

ADJUSTED_AVG_PRICE  FIRST_QUARTILE_PRICE
------------------  --------------------
            490.63                   290
```

Comment: I seem to keep complementing you, I didn't know about ntile. Thanks for the example.